# New DB: Best settings for a BI staging area

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, business-intelligence

I would like to know if there are specific recommended settings when creating a new DB (in SQL Server) which will serve as a staging area DB for BI data flow. In terms of DB use behavior this means:

- quite large tables (from above a mln rows)
- fast growing tables (1-2 mln rows every 4-6 months)
- massive insertion/deletion operation made by ETL

There is something that need to be changed in the default DB properties? Can you specify it carefully?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not really, and FWIW ~5 million rows added every year is not that huge of data. From a performance perspective it's really just going to depend on your specific use cases in BI and how you architect the schema.

Following a star schema design will allow greatest flexibility to the end user when consuming in BI, but you may find certain aggregations or calculations are needed to be pre-processed and stored in a denormalized table to improve performance. Though nowadays [columnstore indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) can be pretty beneficial for running realtime aggregations against large datasets quickly, when used in the right scenarios. But in a table with a lot of deletions, you may find them to *fragment* rather quickly and needing some form of maintenance. (Though I'm not sure if you plan to report directly off of the staging tables or not.)

If your data ever grows such that you find yourself inserting over 1 million rows into your staging tables at a time, you can look into parallelized inserts, which Erik Darling discusses in [Making The Most Of Temp Tables In SQL Server Part 1: Fully Parallel Inserts](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/making-the-most-of-temp-tables-part-1-parallel-inserts/). Specifically you want to look into using the `TABLOCK` hint on your insert statement, which can be utilized regardless if your staging tables are temp tables or real tables. But if you do end up reporting directly out of your staging tables and start to utilize columnstore indexing, then be aware that the `TABLOCK` hint can hurt insert performance, as discussed by Erik also in [How TABLOCK Hints Can Hurt Column Store Insert Performance](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/tablock-isnt-always-better/).